# Excel: Formula or function to sum up the column values starting from a certain row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way (formula or function) in Excel (using `AB` or `RC` format) to sum the column values from a certain row (say row 5) and beyond?

I am trying to place a totals row (say on row 2) above the header (which is on row 4), and each column in the totals row displays the sum of the respective column - all rows from row 5 (which is after the header).

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why a simple [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) won't work here. If you want to be fancy, try something like the following.

```
=sum(a5:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a)))
```

Fill right as necessary.

Comment: Will give a circular reference! Because I want to sum the rows greater than say 5, whereby I (have to) omit the top rows (1-4)

Comment: Did you actually try it before stating that it would not work?

Answer (score 1):

Does SUBTOTAL solve your issue?

```
=SUBTOTAL(9, B5:B1000)
```

9 code for SUM

B5 is the the first cell after the header

Comment: Yes, that would work. I am looking for a better way like `=SUM(C$5:C)`. However this works only in the AB column naming mode and not in RC. Thanks

Comment: @VivekRagunathan, 1,048,576 rows are the maximum allowed. Use this number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, so why don't you just write (in location `X2`, i.e. column X row 2)

```
=SUM(X5:X25)
```

Which will give you the sum of column X rows 5 to 25

Comment: Yes, but my rows don't at 25, they may be 50 or 100. The number of rows has to be assumed automatically. Thanks

Comment: Just use some very big number that it's always bigger that the number of rows in all your columns, for example 100000.  SUM(X5, X100000).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset function for things like this

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A2,3,0,995))
```

where the 995 is the number of rows you want to sum.  You can use a `count()` or something instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Will give a circular reference! Because I want to sum the rows greater than say 5, whereby I (have to) omit the top rows (1-4)

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: It won't throw a circular reference.  A cell can even refer to itself as long as logically it does not depend on its own value.  Try it.

Comment: actually it wasn't working. Today I created a new excel file and copied the cells from the old one. First cut, it seems to work. I will confirm once I test it. Have to do something about the 995. Thanks.